# Enum of another class as parameter

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have this enum in Item class

```
 enum EquipSlot
{
RightHand,
Head,
...
};
```

character class has this function declaration

```
void Character::UnequipSlot(Item::EquipSlot slot);
```

item class is not in any namespace or a part of another class.

i use Item::EquipSlot in implementation a lot with no error. it only gives compile error while in declaration.

What's the correct way to call enum of another class?

(compiler is vc++ 9)
error is :  error C2027: use of undefined type 'Item'  (item class is used in other declarations)

thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you you ask for? Maybe showing us the compiler error would help. So would showing us what exactly you did to get that error and how you used `Item::EquipSlot` not giving you an error. Basically your question needs more information to be answerable

Comment: You might try to convince yourself what's going on by writing the smallest, complete program covering your issue, which then either compiles or fails to compile. Too much ambiguity about your environment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the header that **defines** `Item`.

If `Item` is **only declared**, `Item` may be used in some contexts, but not when the size or contents of `Item` are required.

Comment: i'm using precompiled headers. it was using forward declaration of item class but wasn't enough(why?). now i changed order of character.h and item.h. it worked. it seem forward declaration does not give information enough to use enums.

Comment: @mikbal: That's correct.  A forward declaration only assures the compiler that the class exists.  You'll see from the other uses of `Item` in that file that no other information about `Item` was needed.